# OAuth на яндекс.фотках, Python, HTTP Error 400

Tags: python, urllib

Пишу скриптик на Python, используя urllib2. Хочу получить токен по логину и паролю пользователя.
Вот код:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
auth=urllib.urlencode({'user': 'mutantcornholio', 'password': 'my_passwd', 'client_id': 'my_client_id', 'client_secret': 'my_client_secret', 'grant_type': 'password'})
#Пароли, id, и секрет спрятал. В коде, конечно же, оставил
request = urllib2.Request(url='https://oauth.yandex.ru/token', data=auth)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
```

При запуске имею:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Не могу понять, что делаю не так.
P.S. Опыта у меня крайне мало, могу не понимать некоторые фундаментальные вещи
P.P.S. Первый опыт использования HTTPS и urllib2 вместе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 Bad Request (Плохой запрос) Означает, что сервер обнаружил в запросе клиента синтаксическую ошибку.

Там по моему нужно не `user`, a `username`.

Comment: Блин, и как я это проглядел? И в доках тоже username. Благодарю!